# pip install worked, but module is still not found, Virtual Environment

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, virtual-environment

I am using Conda to run a virtual environment (python version 3.6.5). I am fairly new to coding so please bear with me.

I am trying to

```
from p5 import *
```

However this is returning the following error. . .

```
 (VisCoding) C:\Users\Taha Arif\Desktop\VisCoding>python intro.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intro.py", line 9, in <module>
    from p5 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p5'
```

---

After activating my virtualenv, I performed

```
pip install p5
```

It ran and installed them to my virtualenv. I can see p5 when i run *pip list*.

Can someone provide an explanation on how I can point python to the direction of the p5 module?

Please provide insight as to what python does when looking for a module.

Thanks!

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Did you try including the path to `p5` in your `PYTHONPATH`? Instructions on doing so are in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows

Comment: @pgngp In a virtualenv there is no need to manipulate `PYTHONPATH`.